# If $f(x)=x$, then it is injective, which is stated as $(f(x_1)=f(x_2)\implies (x_1=x_2)$. Does this allow antecedent false and consequent true?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

Let $f(x)=x$.

Let's say I want to show that this function is injective.

Assume

$$f(x_1)=f(x_2)\tag{1}$$

then I immediately get

$$x_1=x_2\tag{2}$$

and so

$$(f(x_1)=f(x_2)\implies (x_1=x_2)\tag{3}$$

which is the desired result.

But what does this mean exactly?

(3) is the same as

$$\lnot (f(x_1)= f(x_2)\lor (x_1= x_2)\tag{4}$$

$$(f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)\lor (x_1= x_2)\tag{5}$$

The truth table for logical or shows that (5) can be true with the first disjunct true (ie, $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$) and the second disjunct true (ie, $x_1=x_2$), but we know this is not true for our function.

In fact, if we assume $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$ then we immediately obtain $x_1\neq x_2$.

Thus it seems that what we ought to have is

$$(f(x_1)=f(x_2)\iff (x_1=x_2)\tag{6}$$

My question is then: how do we reason about the meaning of (3) in logical terms? In particular, does (3) not allow the mathematically impossible case of the antecedent being false and the consequent true?

What if I try the following proof

Assume $(f(x_1)=f(x_2)) \land (x_1\neq x_2)$.

Then $x_1=x_2$ and so $\bot$.

So what can we conclude?

That $\lnot [(f(x_1)=f(x_2)) \land (x_1\neq x_2)]$ which means

$$(f(x_1)\neq f(x_2) \lor (x_1=x_2)$$

Does this mean both disjuncts can be true? Mathematically they cannot.

How do we reconcile the truth of this statement with what we know to be mathematically true?

Comment: We always have $x_1=x_2 \implies f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ when $f$ is a function, so in the context of functions, $f(x_1)=f(x_2) \iff x_1=x_2$ just has logical baggage.  The interesting direction is $f(x_1)=f(x_2) \implies x_1=x_2$

Comment: I had a lapse in concentrtion. As mentioned above, the implication $(x_1=x_2)\implies (f(x_1)\implies f(x_2))$ is simply the definition of a function (and the corresponding notation $f(x)$). Anyway, I think we can actually distill your question to the following: why is it that for a proposition $P$, we have $(\neg P)\vee P$ is true? Do you get ‘confused’ by the truth table for this as well?

Comment: I will point out that your question in propositional logic becomes a bit awkward.  When we write $p \lor q$, then it's either true or false based on the truth values of $p,q$.  It makes no sense to ask whether the disjunction means $p,q$ must simultaneously be able to be true.  When we extend to FOL, we don't add such a restriction.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Great way to distill the question to its essence. From the point of view of just the boolean connective, I think you can construct a truth table with four entries. From the point of view of what is "possible" only two of the entries are possible, namely the two where the truth value of $P$ and $\lnot P$ are opposite.

Comment: Assume $P$. Then, assume $\lnot P$. We have a contradiction. Thus $\lnot\lnot P$. At this point, it appears we can infer $P\implies \lnot\lnot P$. What does it mean to build a truth table for this sentence? How many entries does the truth table have?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I personally believe the confusion arises when you're teaching a computer or a human what an injective function is, and whether you've already accounted for the implicit properties of a *function*, versus a *relation* for example. I can't think of a good way to edit my answer to unambiguously express this, so I recommend readers go through the comments on this answer also.

Yes, (3) by itself does not account for the fact that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ and $x_1=x_2$ are constrained by another relationship: the property of deterministic functions that if you provide the same input, you always get the same output. This is basically the converse of your relation, $(x_1= x_2)\implies (f(x_1) = f(x_2))$, and is a default property for every deterministic function. And so combining the two gives $(f(x_1)=f(x_2))\iff (x_1=x_2)$

So the way I would reason is that (3) is a necessary condition for injective functions. However, it isn't a sufficient condition. That's why you can't simply look at all scenarios which make just (3) true. Though in practice, conditions like $(x_1= x_2)\implies (f(x_1) = f(x_2))$ are usually taken for granted and so people may not bother to explicitly mention it.

Also, unless otherwise specified or known from context clues, functions are assumed to be deterministic.

Comment: Interesting. So when we go to Wikipedia's entry for "Injective Function" and the definition of a function being injective is (3), then this definition is actually not a sufficient condition for the function to be injective ("logically" speaking)? I took a course on first-order logic and it went all the way up to quantifiers. My impression is that I am missing the part where that FOL is linked up to the domain of math.

Comment: (3) is the definition for an injective function (of course once we put in the universal quantifiers), so by definition, it is both necessary and sufficient for a function to be injective.

Comment: An issue with doing proper first-order logic is you have to worry about all the semantics and "unspoken" stuff, like the axioms. If you ask a student about injective function, they'll just say (3), because the converse is obviously true. Why would anyone even think it doesn't hold? I don't if it qualifies as an axiom, but it sounds like one to me. But if you ask a computer, it doesn't have any prior knowledge, bias, or axioms. So it won't realize that the converse is automatically always true unless you tell it.

Comment: @evianpring: It is sufficient for a *function* to be injective. It's not sufficient for a relation to be an injective function. We might, analogously, say that "has four sides of equal length" is sufficient for a rectangle to be a square. It is not sufficient for a quadrilateral to be a square.